# Android - Method call when app is destroyed/closed

Tags: android

I want to call a method when the app is destroyed or closed. At that time the app could be in any activity, so onStop(), onPause() or onDestroy() won't help.
I want to call the method only when the app is destroyed and it should not be dependent on any activity.

Comment: "You can't always get what you want, but if you try sometimes you might get what you need." Let's focus on *why* you want this. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: How are you going to execute code if the app is destroyed? Think about it

Comment: That will piss off the users wouldnt it? I try and close an App but it takes 5 secs to close because its running something. Not good

Comment: There is no way to execute something before app is closed. It is not messaged about it is going to be closed by OS. Only thing you can do is do something on the main Activity's `onStop` for example. This should be called when user is pressing `back` button to close the app.

Comment: @EugenPechanec I wan't to ask the user to rate the app. I wan't that to be done only once the user is done using the app. The app will be used by user when he is stuck in some problems so I don't want to have "rate me" popups coming up at that time. Also, he will be shuffling b/w 3 activities so putting that popup at end of an activity would also not serve the problem.

Comment: When your app is destroyed, no code can be run. You dont control when that happens and if you did, you still cant run any code. Your app is supposed to solve a problem. You should ask for rating after you solve the problem. Help articles ask "was this helpful to you"? Ask for feedback on the article and then ask for feedback on the app.